# Find the last three words of each paragraph if they are shorter than 20 characters in total

Tags: string, code-challenge, parsing, regular-expression

Based on [my SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37302530/321973), but more specifically:

Find a RegEx such that, given a text where paragraphs end with an empty line (or `$` at the very end), match the up to twenty last characters of a paragraph excluding the `\r` or `$` but no more than three *complete* "words" including the "separators" in between and the punctuation following it. The following constraints apply:

- "words" also include abbreviations and the like (and thus punctuation), i.e. "i.e." and "non-trivial" count as one word each
- whitespaces are "separators"
- isolated dashes do not count as "words" but as "separators"
- "separators" *before* the first word must not be included
- trailing punctuation counts to that limit, but not the leading one nor the linebreaks and `$` that must not be in the matching group
- whether trailing punctuation is included in the match or not is up to you

Some examples:

> The early bird catches the **worm. Two words.**
>
> But only if they got **up - in time.**
>
> Here we have a supercalifragilisticexpialidocious **etc. sentence.**
>
> **Short words.**
>
> Try accessing the **.html now, please.**
>
> Vielen Dank **und viele Grüße.**
>
> Did **any-one try this?**

Score is given in bytesteps: bytes multiplied by amount of steps according to https://regex101.com, but there are three penalties:

- if the upper limit of words cannot *trivially*<sup>+</sup> be modified: +10%
- if the upper limit of character count cannot *trivially*<sup>+</sup> be modified: +10%
- failure to handle unicode used in actual words: add the percentage of world population speaking the language according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers&oldid=718585003#Nationalencyklopedin) the failing word stems from. Example: Failing to match the German word "Grüße" as a word => +1.39%. Whether you consider a language's letters as single characters or count the bytes to utf8-encode them is up to you. The penalty does not have to be applied before someone actually provides a counter-example, so feel free to demote your competitors ;)

Since this is my first challenge, please suggest any clarifications. I assume [regular-expression](/questions/tagged/regular-expression) means there are no "loopholes" to exclude.

---

<sup>+</sup> With *trivially* modified I mean expressions such as `{0,2}` and `{21}` are valid but repeating something three times (which would have to be re-repeated to increase the amount words) is not.

Comment: [Bonuses and penalties are generally disliked in challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8106/44713). And, while it makes sense to restrict this to regular expressions, why not remove the tag and let other languages compete as well?

Comment: @VTCAKAVSMoACE I assume because it's not just scored by bytes but also by the number of steps executed by the regex engine, which doesn't make sense for arbitrary languages.

Comment: Could you add test cases where a) there's leading punctuation, b) there's a hyphen that isn't surrounded by whitespace c) a paragraph that consists only of one of two words taking up much less than 20 characters?

Comment: Also the penalties aren't entirely clear. Of course the upper limit of words and characters can *always* be modified, it's just a question of how many places need to be changed. Do you mean `3` and `20` should appear as numbers in a single place which can be changed?

Comment: Will `\s\s+` ever match the paragraph?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thanks for the feedback, I hope my examples and clarifications help. I don't require `3` and `20` to exactly occur, things like `{0,2}` and `{21}` are ok as well. I just wanted to penalize explicit pattern repetitions (e.g. `\w+\s\w+\s\w+` instead of a more generalize-able `(?:\w+\s){0,2}\w+` even though that is longer)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by matching group, i.e. can you specify a particular capturing group as the result?

Comment: @Neil I'd prefer having only one capturing group which would then be the result

Comment: @KennyLau Markdown's manual line-break (two spaces at the end of the line and _no_ empty line) matches that but I wouldn't consider it a paragraph.

Comment: Is there any manual repetition that is not able to be converted into a thing like `{0,2}`?

Comment: Can I match the leading whitespace?

Comment: You should clarify more. I thought the spaces do not count towards the character limit...

Comment: @KennyLau 1) no there isn't but one shouldn't use repetition even if it's shorter 2) matching the leading whitespace is not valid 3) the spaces in between also count towards the character limit - the regex would become pretty complex otherwise I guess?

Comment: 2) Please avoid unclear terms such as "desired".

Comment: @KennyLau Sorry, you're right. Matching it is disallowed.

Comment: I am still not seeing the word "regex" in your question anywhere.

Comment: @KennyLau fixed. I also forgot an example with hyphen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## <s>37 bytes * 1403 steps = 51911 bytesteps</s>

## <s>34 bytes * 1036 steps = 35224 bytesteps</s>

## 37 bytes * 666 steps = 24642 bytesteps

```
(?<!\S)(?!.{21})\S+(( | - )\S+){0,2}$
```

[Verify it here!](https://regex101.com/r/bR7bB7/6)

Comment: I think the challenge is explicitly asking for just a regex, not a solution in any other programming language. So a) you can omit the `!\``, but b) you'll have to make sure in works in PCRE so that it can be scored on regex101.

Comment: I don't think you need the 1 in `{1,3}`, neither in `{1,20}`

Comment: @Bálint He does, otherwise it matches *exactly* 3 words or 20 characters. (And if you mean `{,20}` that only works in Ruby and some other flavours, but definitely not .NET.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner is right I'm afraid, unless you can provide means to calculate an equivalent to regex101's step counting in order to obtain a score in bytesteps. Sorry for the confusion - maybe I should ask a second question that is pure code-golf without the regex-bytesteps, but it would be otherwise identical, so I don't know if that is acceptable

Comment: @MartinBüttner nope, I meant {20}

Comment: @Bálint Yeah that won't work for less then 3 words and 20 characters then. Also Kenny, I don't think your use of `\b` works when the match would start with something other than a word character.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler It's extremely unclear. The word `regex` only appears once throughout your whole question (and it even is a part of the address a website), and it is not even tagged as [tag:regex]

Comment: @KennyLau Sorry about the confusion - unfortunately there is only a tag [tag:regular-expression], I also wanted to use [tag:regex]...

Comment: Oh, I overlooked. Anyhow, the word `regex` still isn't explicitly mentioned in the challenge.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a hyphen-example. That increases the steps (my bad) slightly to [1403](https://regex101.com/r/sV8mL6/2)

Comment: Instead of `(?=.{1,20}$)` you can use `(?!.{21})`, right? The `$` is checked for again at the end anyway. [`(?<!\S)(?!.{21})(\S+ ?(- )?){1,3}$` gives you 34*1036 = 35224 bytesteps](https://regex101.com/r/qM9xR9/2)

Comment: You can get down to 578 steps by replacing [`(?<!\S` with `(?<=\s`](https://regex101.com/r/lK5aF9/2)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Doesn't work for the beginning?

Comment: You're right, I didn't consider that, thanks for pointing it out